# Creating Dataframe in Spark Scala - Which method gives better performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I know there are several ways of creating a dataframe in spark.

1. Using toDF().
2. Using createDataframe().
3. Using spark.read (it can be csv/avro/text/json or any kind of file)

NOTE: There can be any other methods apart from the above three. Will be happy if you mention those methods as well.

Lets say, I'm reading a raw data from HDFS and storing it in a dataframe.
My question is, which of the above methods will give better performance?

I'm a spark practitioner so any useful information provided is highly appreciable.

I will normally use spark.read.text / spark.read.csv to create a dataframe. Kindly suggest which method would be the optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question. To define optimal, you must first define a way to order one method to another:

- The quickest?
- The most easy to use?
- The most easy to read?
- ...

As you can imagine, this can only be answered on a case-by-case basis. And this is in some ways quite subjective as well.

So instead of answering your question directly, I will talk about a tool with which you can decide these questions for yourself (again on a case-by-case basis).

This tool is the `explain` [method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#explain():Unit) on any type of Dataset/Dataframe. As the docs say:

> Prints the physical plan to the console for debugging purposes.

So now, you can have a look at the physical plan for yourself when executing these! You might even get identical physical plans, which would mean that there is no difference at runtime between certain methods. But if the plans are different, you might be able to notice something that will give you a preference toward one or another.

So in your examples, you could do:

```
...toDF().explain
...createDataframe().explain
...spark.read.explain
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is definitely a useful piece of information. Thanks @Koedlt.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the question as answered of you think so, this helps in guaranteeing the quality of Stackoverflow.